# Fragment not changing size of textview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an event the should change the size of a textview in my new fragment that I create the textview is created in my relative layout shared by my new fragment and my old fragment:

```
     Fragment1 rightFragment;
    rightFragment = new Fragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("args", arguments);
    rightFragment.setArguments(args);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, rightFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setTextSize(settings.getFloat("size", 24.0f));
```

When I execute this code in my activity, the textView in my old relative layout is changed, not the new one. How can I make the textView in my new layout work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an argument to your fragment with the size and then set the textView size in the onCreateView method of your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the textview size in the new layout also as you are setting it dynamically. You can use use a float variable to hold the new value of the textsize and then pass it to the new fragment.

You can do something like this:

```
Float textsize = 24.0f;
textView.setTextSize(settings.getFloat("size", textsize));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up solving it a bit different, I will post my own code, but +1.